# ExAws failing when trying to upload with Arc in Phoenix App

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, phoenix-framework

I'm following the guide at https://github.com/stavro/arc for using Arc to upload images.  I'm trying to upload an image with a blog post, but I get the following error in the console which points to some issue with the config, but I don't know what exactly. I've never used AWS S3 before, so I'm flying blind on that side of things.

error:

````
You tried to access the AWS EC2 instance meta, but it could not be reached.
This happens most often when trying to access it from your local computer,
which happens when environment variables are not set correctly prompting
ExAws to fallback to the Instance Meta.

Please check your key config and make sure they're configured correctly:

For Example:
```
ExAws.Config.new(:s3)
ExAws.Config.new(:dynamodb)
```

            (ex_aws) lib/ex_aws/instance_meta.ex:20: ExAws.InstanceMeta.request/2
            (ex_aws) lib/ex_aws/instance_meta.ex:52: ExAws.InstanceMeta.instance_role_credentials/1
            (ex_aws) lib/ex_aws/instance_meta.ex:58: ExAws.InstanceMeta.security_credentials/1
            (ex_aws) lib/ex_aws/config/auth_cache.ex:58: ExAws.Config.AuthCache.refresh_config/2
            (ex_aws) lib/ex_aws/config/auth_cache.ex:33: ExAws.Config.AuthCache.handle_call/3
            (stdlib) gen_server.erl:615: :gen_server.try_handle_call/4
            (stdlib) gen_server.erl:647: :gen_server.handle_msg/5
````

my deps:

```
  defp deps do
    [{:phoenix, "~> 1.3.0-rc"},
     {:phoenix_pubsub, "~> 1.0"},
     {:phoenix_ecto, "~> 3.2"},
     {:postgrex, ">= 0.0.0"},
     {:phoenix_html, "~> 2.6"},
     {:phoenix_live_reload, "~> 1.0", only: :dev},
     {:gettext, "~> 0.11"},
     {:cowboy, "~> 1.0"},
     {:mailgun, "~> 0.1.2"},
     {:arc_ecto, "~> 0.3.1"},
     {:arc, "~> 0.8.0"},
     {:ex_aws, "~> 1.1"},
     {:sweet_xml, "~> 0.6"},
     {:poison, "~> 3.1", override: true}]
  end
```

config.ex:

```
config :arc,
  storage: Arc.Storage.S3, # or Arc.Storage.Local
  bucket: {:system, "iotcimages"}, # if using Amazon S3
  virtual_host: true

config :ex_aws,
  access_key_id: [{:system, "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"}, :instance_role],
  secret_access_key: [{:system, "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"}, :instance_role],
  region: "eu-west-1",
  s3: [
    scheme: "https://",
    host: "s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com",
    region: "eu-west-1"
  ]
```

In prod.secret.ex:

```
config :ex_aws,
  access_key_id: "****",
  secret_access_key: "****"
```

added the below to endpoint.ex:

```
  plug Plug.Static,
    at: "/uploads", from: Path.expand('./uploads'), gzip: false
```

my schema in post.ex:

```
defmodule Iotc.Articles.Post do
  use Ecto.Schema
  use Arc.Ecto.Model
  import Ecto.Changeset
  alias Iotc.Articles.Post


  schema "articles_posts" do
    field :body, :string
    field :mainImg, Iotc.Mainimage.Type, null: :true
    field :slug, :string
    field :snippet, :string
    field :thumbImg, :string, null: :true
    field :title, :string

    timestamps()
  end

  @required_fields ~w()
  @optional_fields ~w(body)

  @required_file_fields ~w()
  @optional_file_fields ~w(mainImage)

  @required_fields ~w()
  @optional_fields ~w(slug)

  @required_fields ~w()
  @optional_fields ~w(snippet)

  @required_fields ~w()
  @optional_fields ~w(title)
```

**UPDATE**

I've now added my config into dev.exs:

```
config :arc,
  storage: Arc.Storage.S3, # or Arc.Storage.Local
  bucket: {:system, "iotcimages"}, # if using Amazon S3
  virtual_host: true

config :ex_aws,
  access_key_id: [{:system, "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"}, :instance_role],
  secret_access_key: [{:system, "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"}, :instance_role],
  region: "eu-west-1",
  s3: [
    scheme: "https://",
    host: "s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com",
    region: "eu-west-1"
  ]
```

And I've add my Keys to a `.env` file:

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=myAccessKey
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=mySecretAccessKey
```

I ran `source .env` prior to starting the server.

I can load the page fine, but again when trying to upload an image in the form, I get an error. Key message seems to be `(RuntimeError) Instance Meta Error: {:error, %{reason: :ehostdown}}`

From the console I've ran `ExAws.S3.list_buckets` which only returns the below so I don't seem to be connect to S3 at all.

```
%ExAws.Operation.S3{body: "", bucket: "", headers: %{}, http_method: :get,
 params: [], parser: &ExAws.S3.Parsers.parse_all_my_buckets_result/1, path: "/",
 resource: "", service: :s3, stream_builder: nil}
```

Comment: Have you set the correct environment variables with the AWS keys? You've put '*' in the code above which leads me to believe you were pasting the actual key itself in the config? The config should have just the env var name and the value should be set from your shell.

Comment: I see what you mean.  I've just updated it and the OP to reflect this change, but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the `:system` atom for `bucket: {:system, "iotcimages"},` you have to use an environmental variable for that bucket as well, as in:

`bucket: {:system, "AWS_S3_BUCKET"},`

If you don't want to use an environment variable for that,`bucket: "my_aws_bucket_name` should work as well